# Como transformar uma query em um json?

Tags: php, json, array

Estou tentando transformar os dados retornados de uma consulta da base de dados no formato Json,  até o momento está quase certo, porém creio que o formato está sendo criado de forma incorreta!

O json está sendo gerado da seguinte forma!

```
[{"codigo":"1","nome":"Lucas Marioano Pereira","nascimento":"05\/12\/2001","perfil":"Administrador","estado":"Bahia","cidade":"Afonso Cl?udio"}]
[{"codigo":"3","nome":"Renata Souza De Jesus","nascimento":"08\/06\/2001","perfil":"Administrador","estado":"Bahia","cidade":"Apiac"}]
```

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$chamaDados = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario")
    or die("Erro na pesquisa" . mysql_error());

while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array( $chamaDados ) ) {  
              $codigo     = $linha['codigo'];
              $nome       = $linha['nome'];
              $nascimento = $linha['nascimento'];
              $perfil     = $linha['perfil'];
              $estado     = $linha['estado'];
              $cidade     = $linha['cidade'];        

  $pessoa =  array(
       array(
          'codigo'     => $codigo,
          'nome'       => $nome,
          'nascimento' => $nascimento,
          'perfil'     => $perfil,
          'estado'     => $estado,
          'cidade'     => $cidade
        )
     );    
   echo $o_json = json_encode( $pessoa ); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Em vez de criar sempre um novo array faz append, dentro do ciclo da seguinte forma

```
  $pessoa[] =
       array(
          'codigo'     => $codigo,
          'nome'       => $nome,
          'nascimento' => $nascimento,
          'perfil'     => $perfil,
          'estado'     => $estado,
          'cidade'     => $cidade
        );
```

declarando antes, a variável $pessoa como um array.

```
$pessoa = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplifique seu código removendo as variaveis `$codigo $nome...` e passe apenas `$linha` e converta o array em json somente após o while:

```
$arr = array();
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array( $chamaDados ) ) {
    $arr[] = $linha;
}
echo $o_json = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu sugeriria fazer como o @jose falou, porém adicionando o id como índice do array. (supondo aqui que código seja o id)

```
$pessoa = array();

while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array( $chamaDados ) ) {
    $pessoa[ $linha['codigo'] ] = array(
          'codigo'     => $linha['codigo'];
          'nome'       => $linha['nome'];
          'nascimento' => $linha['nascimento'];
          'perfil'     => $linha['perfil'];
          'estado'     => $linha['estado'];
          'cidade'     => $linha['cidade']; 
    );  
}

echo $o_json = json_encode( $pessoa );
```

assim, quando você precisar buscar algo no json você facilmente consegue identificar o item usando o índice como id.